# How to parse this XML file using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, ios4

I have an XML file of the following structure:

```
<xmlDocument version="1">
<subject id="1">
<maths marks="65"/>
<science marks="80"/>
<tamil marks="90"/>
<social marks="79"/>
<English marks="70"/>
</subject>
</xmlDocument>
```

How to parse and get this data using Objective C?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an instance of `NSXMLParser` and assign a delegate to the parser.
2. In your delegate class, implement the relevant methods of the `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol.
3. Call the parser's `parse` method.
4. Ask more specific questions if you encounter problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any text inside your tags you can use the `parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict` method on your delegate. Than you can store the values inside a dictionary or object. If you have multiple `subject` tags you can use the `parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName` to change the context of your parser. The official documentation should give you more details on which methods are available.

You could do something like that (incomplete implementation):

```
/*
 * Incomplete implementation just to give some pointers
 */
@implementation MyDelegate
    -(void) init {
        if((self = [super init])) {
            _subjects = [NSMutableArray new];
        }
    }
    -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
        if([elementName equalsIgnoreCase:@"subject"]) {
            _context = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        } else {
            [_context setObject:[attributeDict valueForKey:@"mark"] forKey:elementName];
        }
    }
    - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName {
        [_subjects addObject:_context]
        [_context release]; _context = nil;
    }
@end
```